# About Json reading and writing in python, how to keep the original structure

Tags: python, json

I want to maintain the original structure when I use python to change some value in the JSON, how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean, could give an example ? Also, python might rearrange some field, but the data stays the same

Comment: Hi Hugh -- it would be very useful as @azro says for you to give code examples of what does (and what doesn't) work. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example